# First time Linq user

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Why does this work (it returns only records with last name of Brown)

```
getAll = (from a in getAll where a.PatientLastName.StartsWith("brown") select a);
```

but this doesn't work (it returns all records in the db)?

```
getAll = (from a in getAll where a.PatientLastName.StartsWith(request.FirstName) select a);
```

Where `request.FirstName` is a string field and is equal to "brown".

Comment: Are you changing `request.FirstName` between constructing the query and actually evaluating it?

Comment: No the request object is passed into the method that makes the linq call.

Comment: This sure sounds like `request.FirstName` is actually the empty string.

Comment: Are you sure `request.FirstName` is not equal to `Brown`? It seems to be that this is doing a case-sensitive comparison and fails because they aren't totally the same. Try: `a.PatientLastName.StartsWith(request.FirstName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: The user was adding a '*' to the end of the search string..

Comment: Try adding this:

if (string.IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("no search string")'
}

To test if you're actually getting the value you expect.